# How to add not null in table field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, foreign-keys

```
create table re(id numeric(1),bin varchar(10))
```

how to add not null on table as well as foreign key

Comment: We really need some more info before we can help you. What database technology (Sql Server 200x, MySql, Oracle, ...) are you using?

Comment: Given these questions I ould suggest you find a SQL tutorial on the web or a book

Comment: He added a comment to one of his other question to say sqlserver2k5, so I've updated the tags.

Comment: 18 questions, no answers accepted?  Why bother?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add "NOT NULL" to all the columns you want to prevent from being NULL:

```
create table re(id numeric(1) NOT NULL,
bin varchar(10) NOT NULL)
```

If you want to change it later on, you can do (syntax for SQL Server 2005 and up):

```
ALTER TABLE re
  ALTER COLUMN id NUMERIC(1) NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE re
  ALTER COLUMN bin VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
```

What do you mean by "foreign key" ? On which column ? To which other table and column ?

Check out some of these basic SQL tutorials first - they should get you started:

- [W3Schools SQL Introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_intro.asp)
- [SQL Tutorial](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql.html)

Marc

Comment: If I did help you - why don't you accept my answer? Click on the big "checkmark" to the left of the question. Helps you get a good reputation, too!

Comment: Begging for rep is so undignified, @marc_s :-)

Comment: and I'm trying to educate "domnic" as to how to successfully use and behave on SO :-) You should thank me for that :-)

Comment: +1 for for your "au contraire", it's a good point you raise about education.